# Select all rows from a table where value on a column differs from previous value on that column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let me start first with description of the table I have.

One column is a company id column (integer value), another column is a date in format yyyymmdd (integer value). These two columns taken together uniquely identify the entries in my table. The table (the way I think of it at least) is ordered by Company_id, Date.

The table has several other columns. I will call the one I am interested in mycolumn (integer value). Also sorry for the formatting below but I don't know how to create a proper table over here.

```
Company_id   Date       mycolumn 
1            20121015   1 
1            20121113   1 
1            20130108   2 
1            20130207   2 
1            20130409   2 
1            20130815   1 
2            20050611   7 
2            20080719   7 
4            20091114   3 
4            20091215   3 
4            20100304   5 
4            20110215   5
```

What I am interested in is changes in the mycolumn for each company id and the dates around the change. For example for company with id 1 there are 2 changes (from 1 to 2 and then from 2 to 1), for company with id 2 there are no changes and for company with id 4 there is a single change from 3 to 5. The output table should be:

```
Company_id   Date       mycolumn 
1            20121113   1 
1            20130108   2 
1            20130409   2 
1            20130815   1 
4            20091215   3 
4            20100304   5
```

I know I can do an intermediary step like selecting companies with more than 1 mycolumn value and then use a join statement to exclude the ones with no changes from my table. But I don't know what to do next...

Well, I did come up with something, but it is both messy and not working properly. What I did initially was adding 2 columns with the first and last dates showing up for each company id - mycolumn combination. Then I used several steps to get where I wanted. That works well for companies like the last one where you go from value 3 to value 5, but it messes up for companies like the first one where you go from 1 to 2 and then back to 1...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: First, what queries have you tried to achieve your goal? Second, if you're able to, please don't store dates as integer values. Store them as the correct data type. There's little else more annoying in writing DB queries as having to cast data types that shouldn't need casting to begin with.

Comment: What version of SQL Server is this for?

Comment: What version of sql-server are you using?  Sql Server 2012 added LAG and LEAD which allow you to reference the previous and next row in a query.

Comment: How would you get results 20130108 and 20130409 and not 20130207? You want the system to pick the min and max?

Comment: For MattD - I get the dates in that format and I need to keep them like that as I am going to export the data to another program once I do what I need in SQL.

Comment: I am using the latest version of the Microsoft SQL server. I think it is 2014.

Comment: For xQbert - For the first company, in the mycolumn there is a change from 1 to 2 and I want the last entry with 1 and the first entry with 2. Then there is a change from 2 to 1. I want the last entry with 2 and the first entry with 1. I should get 4 entries in total.

Comment: Thanks Vulcronos, I wasn't aware of those operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lead` and `lag`.

```
with C
(
  select *,
         lag(mycolumn) over(partition by company_id order by Date) as lagmycolumn,
         lead(mycolumn) over(partition by company_id order by Date) as leadmycolumn
  from YourTable
)
select company_id, Date, mycolumn
from C
where mycolumn <> lagmycolumn or
      mycolumn <> leadmycolumn
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked well and I think it's the shortest solution and easiest for me to implement. Also I learned about the lead and lag operators which I didn't know existed.

Comment: Also thanks everyone else for the help and the replies.

Comment: Awesome solution Mikael :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select company_id, mycolumn, max(date) from 
tableName
group by company_id, mycolumn
```

Cheers !!

Comment: Hows does this handle the 20130108 and 20130409 dates? for the same mycolumn and compnyID?  OP wants multiple rows not just max.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think that only selects the last date for each company id, mycolumn combination. It doesn't give me the row before and it doesn't account for situations like the first company where you go from value 1 to 2 and then back to 1 in the mycolumn.

Comment: Thanks but 20130108 & 20130409, there is no change.

Comment: Look at the output table that I want. You did not understand the question. There is a change from 1 to 2 and I want the last entry with 1 and the first entry with 2. Then there is a change from 2 to 1. I want the last entry with 2 and the first entry with 1. I should get 4 entries in total.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.. let me test updated solution and then post.

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest thing in the world, and I'm sure it can be optimised, but this should give you your results:

```
;With Cte As
(
    Select  *, Row_Number() Over (Partition By Company_Id Order By Date) RN
    From    Table
)
Select  *
From
(
    Select  C.company_id, C.Date, C.mycolumn
    From    Cte C
    Cross Apply
    (
        Select  *
        From    Cte X
        Where   X.RN = C.RN + 1
        And     X.company_id = C.company_id 
    ) X
    Where   X.mycolumn <> C.mycolumn
    Union All
    Select  X.company_id, X.Date, X.mycolumn
    From    Cte C
    Cross Apply
    (
        Select  *
        From    Cte X
        Where   X.RN = C.RN + 1
        And     X.company_id = C.company_id 
    ) X
    Where   X.mycolumn <> C.mycolumn
) R
Order By Company_Id, Date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (
    Ident INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    [ROW] INT,
    Company_id INT,
    [Date] INT,
    mycolumn INT
)

INSERT INTO @Tbl
          SELECT NULL,1,20121015,1 
    UNION SELECT NULL,1,20121113,1 
    UNION SELECT NULL,1,20130108,2 
    UNION SELECT NULL,1,20130207,2 
    UNION SELECT NULL,1,20130409,2 
    UNION SELECT NULL,1,20130815,1 
    UNION SELECT NULL,2,20050611,7 
    UNION SELECT NULL,2,20080719,7 
    UNION SELECT NULL,4,20091114,3 
    UNION SELECT NULL,4,20091215,3 
    UNION SELECT NULL,4,20100304,5 
    UNION SELECT NULL,4,20110215,5 

INSERT INTO @Tbl
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Company_id ORDER BY Company_id ASC,[Date] ASC),Company_id,[Date],mycolumn
    FROM @Tbl

DELETE @Tbl WHERE [ROW] IS NULL


SELECT
    t.Company_id,t.[Date],t.mycolumn
FROM @Tbl t
INNER JOIN (
    select
        t1.Ident [Ident1],t2.Ident [Ident2]
    from @Tbl t1 
    INNER JOIN @Tbl t2 ON t1.Company_id=t2.Company_id
        AND t1.[ROW]=(t2.[ROW]-1)
        AND t1.mycolumn<>t2.mycolumn
) delta on t.Ident IN (delta.[Ident1],delta.Ident2)
ORDER BY t.Company_id ASC,t.[Date] ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

2 other answers came in while I was editing this, but I think it's different enough to be worth including - otherwise I wasted all that typing :(

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(CompanyID INT, DateInt INT, MyCol INT);
INSERT INTO @T(CompanyID , DateInt , MyCol) 
    VALUES (1, 20121015, 1), (1, 20121113, 1), (1, 20130108, 2), (1, 20130207, 2), (1, 20130409, 2), (1, 20130815, 1 )
          , (2, 20050611, 7), (2, 20080719, 7), (4, 20091114, 3), (4, 20091215, 3), (4, 20100304, 5), (4, 20110215, 5);
with cteRanked as (
    SELECT CompanyID , DateInt , MyCol, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyID ORDER BY DateInt) as RowNum
    FROM @T
), cteRuns as (
    SELECT T1.CompanyID , T1.DateInt as D1, T2.DateInt as D2
        , T1.MyCol as C1, T2.MyCol as C2
    FROM cteRanked as T1 
        INNER JOIN cteRanked as T2 ON T1.CompanyID = T2.CompanyID and T1.RowNum + 1 = T2.RowNum 
    WHERE T1.MyCol != T2.MyCol
), ctePaired as (
    SELECT CompanyID, D1 as DateInt, C1 as MyCol FROM cteRuns 
    UNION --or UNION ALL to get repeated rows when a run is 1 long
    SELECT CompanyID, D2 as DateInt, C2 as MyCol FROM cteRuns 
)SELECT * FROM ctePaired
ORDER BY CompanyID, DateInt
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using SQL Server 2014 - this is the most efficient way I can find of querying for the sought results. I suspect that there is a better method for "ignoring" CompanyIDs which have had no change.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(CompanyID INT, DateInt INT, MyCol INT);
INSERT INTO @T(CompanyID , DateInt , MyCol) 
VALUES  (1, 20121015, 1), (1, 20121113, 1), (1, 20130108, 2), (1, 20130207, 2), (1, 20130409, 2), (1, 20130815, 1 ),
        (2, 20050611, 7), (2, 20080719, 7), (4, 20091114, 3), (4, 20091215, 3), (4, 20100304, 5), (4, 20110215, 5)

;WITH Stage1 AS
(
    SELECT   *
            ,UseThis    = IIF(LEAD(MyCol, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyID ORDER BY DateInt) != MyCol, 1, 0)
            ,Change     = IIF(LAG(MyCol, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyID ORDER BY DateInt) = 0 OR LAG(MyCol, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyID ORDER BY DateInt) = MyCol, 0, 1)
    FROM @T
)
--  Find companies that have not changed
,Stage2 AS
(
    SELECT *
            ,Inert  = SUM(Change) OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyID)
    FROM Stage1
)
SELECT   CompanyID
        ,DateInt
        ,MyCol
FROM Stage2
WHERE UseThis = 1 
AND Inert != 0
```